# Is Zend_Validate_Int broken for integers 0-9 in in some locales?

Tags: validation, zend-framework

I'm asking this as a question because I can't believe that this popular validator could be broken in this way.  Yet I cannot understand how the behavior shown by the following program can be considered expected behavior.  This is ZF 1.12.  I don't know of a way to report a bug against ZF1, and with Zend_Locale being removed in ZF2, I doubt there's any interest in the ZF team.  I've looked at the Zend source code. and I can't see how this would happen.  Does anybody here have any ideas?  In the particular case where I encountered the problem, the value should be an auto-increment value from a db, so the Digits validator works just as well.  Here is a program demonstrating the problem:

```
<?php
// Put library on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath('./library'),
    get_include_path()
)));

require 'Zend/Locale/Format.php';
require 'Zend/Validate/Int.php';

global $mutating_locales;

echo "\n*** Showing that function checkit() does what's expected with
 a value that has locale-specific formatting\n";
checkit('1000', 'en_US');
checkit('1000', 'hi_IN');
echo var_export($mutating_locales, true) . "\n\n";

echo "\n*** Showing the problem with small integers in locale hi_IN\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < 101; ++$i) {
    checkit((string)$i, 'hi_IN');
}

echo "\n*** Checking every supported locale for value '1'\n";
$mutating_locales = array();
foreach (Zend_Locale::getLocaleList() as $locale => $ignore) {
    checkit('1', $locale);
}
echo var_export($mutating_locales, true) . "\n";

// Function to print if $value is a valid Int in locale $locale
function checkit($value, $locale) {
    global $mutating_locales;
    $formatted = Zend_Locale_Format::toInteger(
                     $value, array('locale' => $locale));
    if ($formatted !== $value) {
        printf("Representation changed for locale %s, old: '%s', new: '%s'\n",
                                             $locale,   $value, $formatted);
        $mutating_locales[] = $locale;
    }
    $validator = new Zend_Validate_Int($locale);
    $valid = $validator->isValid($value);
    if (! $valid) {
        printf("Value '%s' is not a valid Int in locale '%s'\n",
                   $value,                          $locale);
        $invalid_locales[] = $locale;
        if ($formatted === $value) {
            printf("        And the formatted value is identical\n");
        } else {
            $fmtvalid = $validator->isValid($formatted);
            if (fmtvalid) {
        printf("        But the formatted value is valid\n");
        } else {
                printf("        And the formatted value is also invalid\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

$ php validate-int-bug.php

*** Showing that function checkit() does what's expected with
 a value that has locale-specific formatting
Representation changed for locale en_US, old: '1000', new: '1,000'
Representation changed for locale hi_IN, old: '1000', new: '1,000'
array (
  0 => 'en_US',
  1 => 'hi_IN',
)


*** Showing the problem with small integers in locale hi_IN
Value '0' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '2' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '3' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '4' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '5' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '6' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '7' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '8' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '9' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical

*** Checking every supported locale for value '1'
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ar_QA'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ar_SA'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ar_SY'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ar_TN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ar_YE'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'as_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'as'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'bn_BD'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'bn_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'bn'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dv_MV'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dv'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dz_BT'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dz'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'en_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'en_PK'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'gu_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'gu'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hy_AM'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hy'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kn_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kn'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kok_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kok'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ml_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ml'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'mr_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'mr'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'or_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'or'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa_PK'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'sa_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'sa'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'bn'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dv_MV'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dv'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dz_BT'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'dz'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'en_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'en_PK'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'gu_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'gu'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hi'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hy_AM'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'hy'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kn_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kn'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kok_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'kok'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ml_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'ml'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'mr_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'mr'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'or_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'or'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa_PK'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'pa'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'sa_IN'
        And the formatted value is identical
Value '1' is not a valid Int in locale 'sa'
        And the formatted value is identical
```

**Edit:** I found out how to post a ZF1 issue, so this is now posted at https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/166 , which also refers to this post.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question ([Zend_Validate_Float locale not working with hi_IN locale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23195934/3351765)) that has been asked and is related to yours.
I put an response and I think it might also interest you.
:)
In summary, I am proposing is to add `'0` 'before the number (replace `'1'` by `'01'`) or modify the `Zend/Local/Format.php` file  (the details are in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295239/3351765)).

Comment: Thanks very much for making this connection!  As it happens, my site does not need to support the locales that have problems, I only encountered the issue in testing.  But I don't understand how adding a 0 prefix is a workaround since it means noticing the bad value and changing it before the filter, which kind of defeats the purpose of the filter.  I didn't dig into your regex solution since it means modifying released ZF sources.  What I did to satisfy testing was change to use the 'digits' filter.  Doesn't help the other question, though, which is dealing with float...

Comment: And note that you can't just blindly insert a 0 prefix without examining the string first, e.g. possible sign, and the need to prevent it from being treated as octal.

Comment: Thank you for these returns. I agree that we should not modify the source Zend but I thought it was not maintained, I suggested that, especially that the problem comes from a private function.
Through you I now know that Zend1 is not dead and we must now wait for the correction. Regarding the '0 'before, I agree, you should check if there is a sign.