# Zend_Validate_Float locale not working with hi_IN locale

Tags: zend-framework

While working with number validation with 'hi_IN' I am facing following problem.

where Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat is working fine for non single digit and any locale

but not working for single digit and locale 'hi_IN'

> Source Code : (test cases)

```
foreach (array('en_GB','en_US', 'lo_LA', 'hi_IN') as $locale) {

    foreach (array('12', '1') as $value) {

        if (!Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat($value, array('locale' => $locale))) {
            echo $value .' ==> '. $locale .' TRUE <br>';
        } else {
            echo $value .' ==> '. $locale .' FALSE<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

> OutPut of above script

```
12 ==> en_GB  FALSE
1 ==> en_GB   FALSE
12 ==> en_US  FALSE
1 ==> en_US   FALSE
12 ==> lo_LA  FALSE
1 ==> lo_LA   FALSE
12 ==> hi_IN  FALSE
1 ==> hi_IN   TRUE
```

So the issue is that how can i fixed this for hi_IN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/166 For detail about this issue

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the management patterns for decimal .
But ZF1 is (to my knowledge) no longer maintained .

After several tests, I can proposes two solutions:

- The first is to add a `'0'` before your number. (replace `'1'` by `'01'`).
- The second is to modify the `Zend/Local/Format.php` file.
  In the private static function `_getRegexForType` replace :

  ```
      if (strpos($pattern, ',') !== false) {
          $parts = explode(',', $pattern);
          $count = count($parts);
          foreach($parts as $key => $part) {
              switch ($part) {
                  case '#':
                  case '-#':
                      if ($part[0] == '-') {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[' . $symbols['minus'] . '-]{0,1}';
                      } else {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[' . $symbols['plus'] . '+]{0,1}';
                      }

                      if (($parts[$key + 1]) == '##0')  {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]{1,3}';
                      } else if (($parts[$key + 1]) == '##') {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]{1,2}';
                      } else {
                          throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 1):"' . $pattern . '"');
                      }
                      break;
                  case '##':
                      if ($parts[$key + 1] == '##0') {
                          $regex[$pkey] .=  '(\\' . $symbols['group'] . '{0,1}[0-9]{2})*';
                      } else {
                          throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 2):"' . $pattern . '"');
                      }
                      break;
                  case '##0':
                      if ($parts[$key - 1] == '##') {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]';
                      } else if (($parts[$key - 1] == '#') || ($parts[$key - 1] == '-#')) {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '(\\' . $symbols['group'] . '{0,1}[0-9]{3})*';
                      } else {
                          throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 3):"' . $pattern . '"');
                      }
                      break;
                  case '#0':
                      if ($key == 0) {
                          $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]*';
                      } else {
                          throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 4):"' . $pattern . '"');
                      }
                      break;
              }
          }
      }
  ```

By:

```
        if (strpos($pattern, ',') !== false) {
            $parts = explode(',', $pattern);
            $count = count($parts);
            $flag = false;
            foreach($parts as $key => $part) {
                switch ($part) {
                    case '#':
                    case '-#':
                        if ($part[0] == '-') {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[' . $symbols['minus'] . '-]{0,1}';
                        } else {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[' . $symbols['plus'] . '+]{0,1}';
                        }

                        if (($parts[$key + 1]) == '##0')  {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]{1,3}';
                        } else if (($parts[$key + 1]) == '##') {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]{1,2}';
                        } else {
                            throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 1):"' . $pattern . '"');
                        }
                        break;
                    case '##':
                        if ($parts[$key + 1] == '##0') {
                            $flag = true;
                            $regex[$pkey] .=  '(\\' . $symbols['group'] . '{0,1}[0-9]{2})*';
                        } else {
                            throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 2):"' . $pattern . '"');
                        }
                        break;
                    case '##0':
                        if ($parts[$key - 1] == '##' && !$flag) {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]';
                        } else if (($parts[$key - 1] == '#') || ($parts[$key - 1] == '-#') || (($parts[$key - 1] == '##') && $flag)) {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '(\\' . $symbols['group'] . '{0,1}[0-9]{3})*';
                        } else {
                            throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 3):"' . $pattern . '"');
                        }
                        break;
                    case '#0':
                        if ($key == 0) {
                            $regex[$pkey] .= '[0-9]*';
                        } else {
                            throw new Zend_Locale_Exception('Unsupported token for numberformat (Pos 4):"' . $pattern . '"');
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I added a `$flag` variable that can manage the decimal form of the '`#,##,##0.###`'
I did some tests and it looks run.
Not being an expert in the regulars expressions don't hesitate to send me a return.
:)

Comment: if i remove locale it working fine for float without checking number format.

Comment: Where have you remove locale? in `Zend_Locale_Format::isFloat($value, array('locale' => $locale)`?

Comment: Actually, I also vaguely thought that ZF1 was not being maintained, but I see they just released 1.12.6 two weeks ago: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1 .  You can enter new issues for ZF1 at https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/new

Comment: @sootsnoot:Thank you very very much for this returns. I informed the problem on github with my solution. :)